# reading data, one number at a time, from file to be used in a formula

Tags: import

First off let me say that I am a total nube.  I saw some examples of answers "close" to my question but I did not understand them :-(

I want to read individual numbers in from a text file and have those numbers be used in an equation (more specifically I am trying to read option volatility which will then be used in an option pricing model).

if easy, I would like to read 3 numbers at a time {a,b,c} and have them be used in an equation as well.  Solve the equation and have the input values {a,b,c} and the results f[a,b,c] sent to a new file.

sorry for the trivial question but i am struggling with learning the appropriate syntax (too many years of VB ;-)

Thanks to all that help

Best
John

Comment: the best approach is usually to `Import` the whole file, and process from there.  If you really want to read a line at a time the relevant commands are `OpenRead` , `ReadList` , etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input is comma delimited, the following should do the trick:

```
data = Import["C:\\Users\\nqduy\\Desktop\\test.txt", "CSV"]
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}

partition = Partition[data[[1]], 3]
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}

Map[f, partition]
> {f[{1, 2, 3}], f[{4, 5, 6}], f[{7, 8, 9}], f[{10, 11, 12}]}
```

This procedure can be done in one line but this is easier to follow.

Comment: thank you for this, could I trouble you to include a simple example where the 3 numbers are multiplied together (via a function) after being read

Comment: In this particular case, you can use `Apply` instead of `Map`:
   `Apply[Times, partition, {1}]`

Comment: Thank you nqduy, but I used that multiplication as random an example.  I am having trouble reading single numbers in and using them as input in a financial function.  I have a BlackScholes option pricing model and one of the input parameters is volatility.  It is this volatility that I want to read and used.  When I read the file i do not have the ability to take each individual number (volatility) and use it in the option pricing model. That is why I was looking for a generic function that can be solved by using data imported one at a time.  Sorry if this is a bit wordy.   Thanks again. John